# Find the Upper and lower sums on a regular partition of the intervals, for the following integral:

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

[Original question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1sKa.png)

> $$\int_1^2 f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$$
>   where
>   $$f(x)=\begin{cases}
>  1 & \text{if $x$ is rational,} \\
>  0 & \text{if $x$ is irrational}
> \end{cases}$$

How does one interpret this to find the upper and lower sums on a regular partition

$$\Delta x={1\over n}$$

Comment: The values of x are 0, 1/n, 2/n, 3/n, ..., (n-1)/n, 1.  Each pair of successive x values, 0 to 1/n, 1/n to 2/n, etc.  gives an interval.  To find the "upper sum" take the largest value of f in each interval.  To find the "lower sum", take the lowest value of f in each interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values of x are 0, 1/n, 2/n, 3/n, ..., (n-1)/n, 1.  Each pair of successive x values, 0 to 1/n, 1/n to 2/n, etc.  gives an interval.  To find the "upper sum" take the largest value of f in each interval.  To find the "lower sum", take the lowest value of f in each interval.  For this particular interval that is very easy- in ANY interval there exist both rational and irrational numbers so the largest value of f in any interval is 1 and the smallest is 0,  1 times 1/n is 1/n and 0 times 1/n is 0.  Adding 1/n n times gives 1 and adding 0 n times gives 0.